# If you inherit a Roth 401(k), is it taxed?

Tags: united-states, taxes, inheritance, roth-401k

My understanding is that a Roth IRA can be inherited and the U.S. government doesn't put an inheritance tax on it.

Does that also apply to a Roth 401(k)? In other words, if I died, would my children inherit my Roth 401(k) without that 401(k) facing an inheritance tax?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, no.

True, a Roth has no income tax. The tax was already paid on deposit and no more tax due.

But, the Roth, IRA or 401, still might be subject to estate tax, as it is still part of the estate for state and federal estate tax purposes. Keep in mind, the federal estate exemption is high, over $11M per decedent. State varies, by, well, state.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on whether the [SECURE Act](https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/house-bill/1994) becomes law<sup>1</sup>, your children may be forced to withdraw from the Roth account faster than you might like. It changes the Required Minimum Distribution (RMD) rules.

As I understand it, the bill says a non-spousal inheritor must empty the account within 10 years of your death.

While not a tax *per se,* it makes your scheme somewhat less attractive.

---

<sup>1</sup> As of this writing, the bill has passed the House of Representatives, but not the Senate.

<sup>2</sup> As of this edit, the bill has passed the Senate as well.

Comment: I'm curious as to what would happen if someone didn't empty the account within 10 years, where does this money go? Free money to the government which had already been paid for it?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton my guess is the financial institution is required to disburse the remainder after the 10 years are up.

Comment: @GOATNine So essentially "Distribute the funds within 10 years, or we will do it for you"?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton usually along the lines of "You have x time to empty the account before we close it". There are guidelines that then allow them to declare the account abandoned after a certain period of no contact. They do have to make every effort to reach you though.

Comment: @GOATNine So if the account is abandoned, the institution just keeps the money?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I think it would just become unclaimed property. Just because the owner hasn't withdrawn it doesn't mean it reverts to the account manager.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton The institution is allowed to close out abandoned accounts. YMMV by jurisdiction though. What happens to the money also depends on the institution and local laws.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton: The formal term for what chepner has mentioned is "escheatment". https://www.sec.gov/fast-answers/answersescheathtm.html

Comment: @BenVoigt Thank you, this answers all of my questions!

Comment: The details once this rule passes are a bit convoluted. A number, $500K is exempt from the withdrawal requirement. Also, the laws regarding escheat are another issue. The account holder (beneficiary) is unlikely to ignore the account. Any withdrawal or trade restarts the clock on possible escheat.

Comment: Can "empty the account"  be " rollover into my own Roth"?

Comment: One can only roll into their own account the account of their deceased spouse (or divorced, if court ordered). A non-spouse inheritance must remain titled as an inherited acct.